# Agrupar resultado de consultas unidas por UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, group-by

¿Buenas tardes, me podéis echar una mano por favor?
Necesito generar un listado que me devuelva, dado intervalo de fechas o de números de pedido, una relación de los artículos y unidades totales que se encuentran en estos pedidos:
Esto lo logro con esta consulta:

```
select DE.ARTICULO, DE.DEFINICION,SUM(UNIDADES)
from detalle_pedido as DE INNER JOIN cabecera_pedido as CA
ON DE.NUMERO = CA.NUMERO AND DE.LETRA = CA.LETRA
WHERE DE.NUMERO='  20000014' OR DE.NUMERO= '  20000023' 
GROUP BY DE.ARTICULO,DE.DEFINICION 
HAVING SUM(UNIDADES)>0
```

El problema, es que el ERP donde lanzo esta consulta, separa los ejercicios por bases de datos, por lo que esta consulta solo me funcionará en un ejercicio concreto.
Me da que la solución sería con un UNION ALL, y unir el resultado a la misma consulta en otro ejercicio, pero de esta manera me saldrán duplicados los artículos que se en encuentren en pedidos de ejercicios diferentes.
¿Como podría volver a agrupar y sumar las unidades del resultado del UNION ALL?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo que un `UNION ALL` sea la forma más eficiente de hacerlo, aunque es del todo factible. En este caso, el `UNION` lo debes realizar de los datos en si, sin agregaciones y la agregación la realizas del total de uniones.

En este ejemplo he puesto la unión de dos consultas en dos bases de datos distintas (BD1 y BD2)

```
SELECT ARTICULO, DEFINICION, SUM(UNIDADES)
FROM (
   select DE.ARTICULO, DE.DEFINICION, UNIDADES
   from BD1.dbo.detalle_pedido as DE 
   INNER JOIN BD1.dbo.cabecera_pedido as CA
   ON DE.NUMERO = CA.NUMERO AND DE.LETRA = CA.LETRA
   WHERE DE.NUMERO='  20000014' OR DE.NUMERO= '  20000023' 
   UNION ALL
   select DE.ARTICULO, DE.DEFINICION, UNIDADES
   from BD2.dbo.detalle_pedido as DE 
   INNER JOIN BD2.dbo.cabecera_pedido as CA
   ON DE.NUMERO = CA.NUMERO AND DE.LETRA = CA.LETRA
   WHERE DE.NUMERO='  20000014' OR DE.NUMERO= '  20000023'
   ) a
GROUP BY ARTICULO, DEFINICION
HAVING SUM(UNIDADES) > 0
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias. ¿Qué otro método es el que consideras más eficiente, no es necesario que te explayes en la respuesta, ya me documentaré, pero serías tan amable de indicarme cuál sería el método más adecuado? Gracias.